# what is the maximum number of vertices in a regular graph with fixed diameter

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Suppose a $k$-regular graph G of diameter $d$. I am going to prove $|V(G)|=n$, $n\le [k(k-1)^d-2]/(k-2)$ if $k > 2$  I need some hint for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Fix any node as a root, branch $k$ ways, and repeat for each of the children, branching $k-1$ ways for them. After the root node at level $r=0$, there are $k(k-1)^{r-1}$ nodes for level $r>0$, up to level $r=d$. Now sum a finite geometric series.

Comment: It seems false to me.. this reasoning suggests that $n\le k^d$ that is much more than the thesis

Comment: Sorry, it is $(k-1)$-way branching after level 1. I corrected the answer just now. This is called the *Moore bound*.

Comment: Also, the original question was missing a ^.